# Setting Relative Coinage Values

Tags: internal-consistency, economy, money

Lets say you had a state, technologically around the mid to late classical era, using a hard coinage. There are four types of coins:

- The smallest coin is a paulum.
- The second smallest is the radix, worth 12 paulum by law.
- The third smallest is the decim, worth 12 radix, again by law.
- Finally the aureus, worth 12 decim. This would be set to a hard weight of perhaps half an ounce of gold.

Is this a practical/realistic monetary system? Would this be stable economically, assuming the regulations are strictly adhered to? How does it interact with (particularly w/r/t trade) other realms?

Comment: ? What's the major difference between this system and the historically well known Roman system -- 1 aureus (about 8 grams or 1/4 ounce of gold) = 25 denarii (about 4 grams or 1/8 ounce of silver) = 100 sestertii (tiny silver coin or large token bronze coin) = 400 asses (token copper coins, weight irrelevant) = 1600 quadrantes? It worked for the Romans for about half a millennium.

Comment: Or the [Turkish system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Economy_of_Turkey#Data) which underwent [hyperinflation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperinflation) in the 80s, 90s and 2000s? Economic stability depends on more than coins and pieces of paper. It's worth looking at how the money is anchored to the country's economy, eg. the [Gold Standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gold_standard) as a study of how to attempt to create stability.

Comment: @AlexP is is based on the Roman system, but it differs in that it's not commodity money, which, as far as I've been able to tell, is what the Romans used. The physical value of the paulum is what the law says it is, and not what the coin itself is made of. This makes for a sort of mixed commodity and representative money system which I can't find a direct historical analogue of, although I suppose it's probably close enough that it can just be treated as a representative system.

Comment: In the Roman system, the denarius was the smallest coin with intrinsic value. The (imperial) sestertius, and the lower denominations (the *as* and its subdivisions) were tokens at all times, with their value being what the law said it was.

Comment: @AlexP if the asses had irrelevant weight, what stopped people from scapping the sides of the coin for extra metal? The english did it....

Comment: @Green: Nothing stopped them, if they really wanted a bit of very very expensive copper. Imperial sestertii, and the *as* and lower denominations at all times, were made of base metal (bronze or copper). They were token coins, of which the value was set by law, not by the amount of metal in them; that is, 1 HS = by definition 1/4 of a denarius or 1/100 of an aureus, 1 *as* = by definition 1/16 of a denarius or 1/400 of an aureus. (The English briefly and the Swedes for a longer time *did* make copper coins of intrinsic value. They were huge and utterly impractical. Look for "cartwheel penny".)

Comment: Mid to late classical era, so we're talking Roman Republic and Emperor age. Your system would do fine on earth, with Copper, Bronze, Orichalcum, plated Silver, Silver, plated Gold and gold. It resembles the late-Roman habit of introducing ever smaller coinage, derived from a gold piece that rises in value - or lowers in weight - all the time, as the economy expands. As long as your population won't explode, your system will do fine.

Comment: Maintaining the Roman analogue and below answers, you could consider double denominations (Roman: *dupondius*) or half (*quadrans*) denominations, to limit the change amounts. Keep in mind the Romans needed big and very heavy money stashes in their homes, to store all their coins. Moving money in large amounts required weeks long expeditions with army protection.

Comment: I imagine the people who came up with such a monetary system probably have an extra finger on each hand, for a total of 12.  Our 10 fingers are probably the main reason we've been stuck using base 10 for millennia.  There are actually many advantages to a duodecimal math system - there are advocates to this day who recommend it, but we're far too entrenched in our decimal number system for that to ever be a serious possibility.

Comment: The Romans never introduced a strict divider system like the above. The Greek and Roman coinage existed for about 1000 years, and for the small coins everybody used, it was binary: based on halving (Quadrans-Semis-As) and doubling (Drachme-Didrachme, As-Dupondius) and a decimal system played a role when higher denominations got involved. A Denarius, originally Didrachme (double drachme) was worth 10 Asses. A gold Aureus was 20 Denarii. Duodecimal is anglosaxon, rather than Roman. It can be maintained: In Great Britain, they maintained the sixes and duodecimal system until 1971.

Comment: @DarrelHoffman Base 10 isn't necessarily the default even for humans. The most extreme other numbering system I've heard about is base 27, roughly due to the number of joints on a body. It could be easy to rationalize base 12 as the knuckles on one hand with the thumb as a marker.

Comment: @Goodies: A denarius was 16 asses. (Yes, *originally* it was 10 asses, hence the name. But the *as* got retariffed to 1/16 or a denarius very soon, and for the overwhelming majority of time it was 1/16 of a denarius. Similarly, a sestertius *"semis tertius"* was originally 2 1/2 asses, but when the *as* was retariffed to 1/16 or a denarius the sesterius remained at 1/4 of a denarius and thus became the equivalent of 4 asses. The 16-4-1 denarius-sestertius-as ratio prevailed for centuries.)

Comment: @DarrelHoffman British coinage used subdivisions of 2, 3, 4, 6, 8, 12 and 20 at various times in history. No factors of 10 involved. (There was a coin with the value of 1/10 of a pound, but it name implied "2/20" not "1/10")

Answer (score 15):

There is nothing wrong with these denominations. If your culture uses duodecimal math, go with it.

However, if you want this system to be stable over a long period of time, you need to think about common issues like gold/silver price fluctuations, coin clipping and, for the authorities, eternal temptation to reduce metal amount in the coins.

Comment: Precious metal price fluctuations are due to those metals not *being* the standard for value.  If your money *is* gold and silver, their values don't fluctuate (though values of goods might due to scarcity or demand) -- the only real concern is that if, say, a major silver mine plays out, the cost of silver *relative to copper or gold* might increase.

Comment: @Zeiss Ikon it's not just "might increase" - scarcity or overabundance of precious metals played havoc with many countries' finances in the past. Any metal-based fiscal system is doomed from the start and can't last for long without a reform.

Comment: And yet, a fiat currency (one not based on some kind of tangible) has other issues, most notably inflation as a normal condition and *runaway* inflation as an ever-present specter -- with the modern US economy as one example, and that of Argentina over the past half century as another.

Comment: Worth noting that though gold has gone from  USD 35/oz to peaks above USD 2500/oz over the past century, price of *stuff* in grams of gold fluctuate only a little.

Comment: @Zeiss Ikon of course no monetary system is perfect. And "price of stuff in grams of gold fluctuate only a little" is exactly because we moved away from the gold standard. The _amount_ of stuff in the world increased manifold over the last century, while the _supply_ of gold only a little.

Comment: And yet, despite gold increasing price by a factor of almost 60, *stuff* kept right up with it over that same time.  We don't have a shortage of *stuff* like we do of gold, so there's a flaw in that argument somewhere.

Comment: @Zeiss Ikon _stuff_ increased much more than 60 times in the last century.

Comment: Right.  So why did the *price of stuff* increase by a factor of 60?

Comment: @Zeiss Ikon the _price_ didn't (mostly). The _amount_ did.

Comment: Compared the price of (milk, locally made tools, books, almost any other hard goods) between 1920 and 2020?  Gas is only about 10x, but cars are 50x -- unless you price in grams of gold.

Comment: @Zeiss Ikon kindly asking you to also compare the _amount_ of gas and cars produced in 1920 and 2020.

Comment: Producing more won't raise the price -- usually lowers unit prices.  Turning dollars loose from any real goods (for the purpose of "creating money") does.

Comment: @Zeiss Ikon my point is that if we kept gold coins, we couldn't have enough to pay for all the gas and all the cars that are sold in 2020.

Comment: The other major limit is your economy can only be as big as the amount of gold your country has, which was a serious limitation, it basically prevented economic growth many times in history.

Answer (score 10):

#### You may want more precision

You may want another coin or two. Whether its 1/12 a paulum or 12 aureus or one of each is open for debate and subject to how these coins are anchored to real value.

I'm assuming you've chosen 12 here because it divides nicely, implying you don't want to see prices like "3.126 paulum" or "1 and 78/144 paulum". The paulum should be the smallest useful chunk of value.

Currently your smallest coin and your largest coin are 1728-fold difference in value. That's sounds like a lot, but mapping it onto modern economics it doesn't seem like it has both enough precision at the low end and enough convenience at the high end.

To explain - I'm just going to assume I'm using your system in modern day Australia and am just mapping your coins to different value pegs.

**If we map 1c AUD to 1 paulum - large scale transactions are impractical**

Even though the minimum coin here is 5c, and we want to take it out of circulation because it isn't as useful in modern economics as it once was due to its popularity and inflation, you are still billed to 1c level of accuracy in the modern world. I can buy or sell shares at an accuracy of $0.01, and if my 50c each shares go up in value 2% I want to keep that value. Some of my shares paid a 3c each dividend last year. The casino still has 1c slot machines. Currency conversions are performed accurate to usually 0.1 cents, and my pay rate is set accurate to 1 cent per hour.

Working with this accuracy floor them the paulum maps to the penny, the smallest representable value, the largest modern value I can represent with one coin is $17.28, below minimum wage here. If your currency is multiples of 12 and your low skill workers are taking home 12 of the largest coin after a full days work something isn't right.

The cost of buying a nice house in this system would be 40000 auerus. That's a lot to count at settlement. Transporting an armies pay to them would require significant logistics.

**If we map the aureus to a large amount, we don't have enough small change.**

Going of your example of 1/2 ounce of gold, you can buy a house without a wheelbarrow to carry your payment, but you don't have enough small change to deal with day to day transactions.

Gold is currently trading at 1,806.38 AUD / ounce. Dividing that out, a paulum is worth 52c. That's pretty large for a smallest denomination.

A $1.04 loaf of bread can only be sold at full price or half price.

Your choices for tipping on a $3.12 cup of coffee is 0%, 16.6% and 33%.

A "premium" product could not retail for less than 52c in value above that of the "economy" product. I hope your car doesn't need premium petrol, as if normal petrol is 3 coins per litre (1.56/L), premium would have to be $2.08/L, otherwise it's the same price.

**So what to do?**

My suggestion is add a "twelfthum" or something, a 1/12th chunk of a paulum allowing for more precision in small values.

Because this turns a real estate transaction from 40,000 coins to 3,500 coins (which is still a lot). My second suggestion is a higher value coin so real estate deals and bank to bank settlements and company pay deliveries etc. don't need heavy haulage.

Comment: No one is counting $100 bills when selling a house (well, most of the time).

Comment: In the UK until the 17th century the spread in value of currency was only 960-fold, from the farthing to the sovereign.

Comment: @Alexander because most are done with a mortgage, and those that don't, we have EFT that does the counting for us and displays a balence. If you have no better store of value than a \$100 note, then you're counting \$100 notes when buying a house.

Comment: @Mike Scott: Until the 20th century, US coins (not bills) had a range of 4000-fold, from the half cent piece to the 20 dollar double eagle" gold piece.  (This doesn't include modern bullion coins, that have a precious metal value that has no relation to their face value.)  At today's gold price, the 35 g double eagle would be worth about 2000 dollars, so a couple hundred would buy a typical US house.

Comment: @Ash large amount cashless transactions had become the norm long before EFT. Besides, if one aureus is "perhaps half an ounce of gold", then (according to your projection), a nice house would be an equivalent of 1250 pounds of gold, which makes gold fairly cheap, and thus an inconvenient store of value.

Comment: @Alexander I anchored my answer to the lower end of the range but starting from the upper end the same issue applies. Gold is currently 1,806.38 AUD /ounce. That means you're smallest coin is worth over $1.

Comment: @Ash - actually, coin's worth is half of that - which is not that bad for the vast majority of our purchases. We can calculate our finances to the smallest fraction - but then actual transaction would be rounded to a larger value.

Comment: @Alexander Yeah you're right I forgot the "half". Still a $1.04 loaf of bread costing 2 coins can only be sold at full price or 50% off. Would be nice to be a bit more granular in pricing at the retail level.

Comment: Nice answer, however comments also point rigth things, existed systems. It also may be a difference of life styles of different time. One does not buy a loaf of bread(1 buck, maan so inflated, lol) but few kg of bread for a whole family for a dinner, bag of corn etc. Also purchase pover is not necesarly linear with denomination power, if a worker(80-90 percent of non nobles) gets 10 lowest denomination coins a day and his daily expenses are 9 of them(rent food) then it takes around 5 years to save for high denomination coin and a price of 10-50 such coins cuts them out of the market completly.

Comment: In that sense class devision upper, middle, low and class segregation by where they live can be reflected(?) in that you package stuff differently, different good obiviously, different marketing of those goods so to speak, so no wonder they didn't need wider separation of low and high money. Gold is not the most expensive store of value now or back then - gems work nicely, land. Poor to poor interaction - barter works well enough if needed for small stuff. Everything which can't be grown has to be expensive, poor you do not need that etc. Maybe a half pence or something like that is enough

Comment: @MolbOrg small transactions were pretty common in the old times, for example you can check this video about "fast food" in ancient Rome https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v5Qz00eUF5Q&list=PLkOo_Hy3liEKUONCNxFP1q-sLmTqOisJZ&index=4

Comment: @SJuan76 not so convinient for me to watch it rigth now, I'll try it in the future. I have seen some video about bar/fast food place in Pompeii so I can imagine. My local currency nominally has 50'000 separation, but it useless and for convinience usually prices are round up making it effectively 5000, but snak for 1/500 of high coin -  choices are quite limited(one known to me), so for practical uses 500 range is quite enough, so 1728-fold  is well enough. And house worth more or less a 500-1000 of high coins here. Small round ups can be made in goods themselfs, by design and negotiations.

Comment: Also it worth mentioning that for the most of Roman history their coin separation was less than 1728.

Answer (score 6):

There are a couple of issues I see with the proposed system. The first is the possibility of a scale mismatch, and the second is that it leads to *lots* of spare change.

The first is relatively nicely covered in Ash’s answer, so I won’t do more than summarize it here, but it comes down to the simple fact that unless the roughly 4 orders of magnitude difference in value between the highest and lowest value coins roughly corresponds to the difference in value between the highest and lowest value goods traded in everyday commerce in your world, you’ll run into issues (either people splitting coins to pay for small stuff (this actually happened historically), or needing to have absurd numbers of coins to pay for big stuff).

The problem of spare change is a bit different. The issue that arises is that the more change you have to make for a purchase, the more room for error there is and the longer it will take, and in your case your system tends to produce a lot of change.

As a baseline for comparison, assuming a merchant can always provide minimum change, the decimal system in use by the US and some other parts of the world, with 1, 5, 10, 25, and 50 unit coins and bank notes starting at 100 units is actually reasonably optimal because you will never need more than 10 total coins to make change, and any given denomination will not be needed more than four times. Various other decimal systems (such as the Euro system with 20 Euro cent coins instead of 25) are marginally different, but still similarly close to optimal. It’s technically possible to make even more optimal systems, but they require really wonky values for the coins that don’t divide into each other nicely.

In your system though, things get a bit crazy. With four coins in a duodecimal relation like you have, you may need up to 33 coins for minimum change, and may need any of the denominations up to 11 times. That’s a *lot* of coins compared to 10 and 4 for the two-tier decimal system mentioned above, and that, in turn, means that your merchants may need a nontrivial amount of time for each transaction simply to count change.

For a duodecimal system like this, there are two practical options for minimizing number of coins needed for minimum change: thirds and sixths.

Using thirds as your subdivision would give you coins with values of 1 unit and 4 units for each unit type. This translates to 8 different types of coins (assuming you do 4 aureus coins), needing no more than 15 for minimum change with any coin needed no more than 3 times (the worst case minimum translates to three 1 paulum, two 4 paulum, three 1 radix, two 4 radix, three 1 decim, and two 4 decim). This keeps your total number of denominations down while still doing a pretty good job cutting down on coins needed for minimum change.

Using sixths as your subdivision would give you coins with values of 1 unit, 2 units, 4 units, and 6 units for each unit type. THis translates to 16 different types of coins (assuming you do 2, 4, and 6 aureus coins), needing no more than 12 for minimum change with any coin needed no more than once (the worst case minimum translates to one each of every coin below 1 aureum). This is the absolute lowest you can get your minimum change requirements with a duodecimal system such as you have outlined, but gives you a lot of denominations to worry about.

Comment: +1 good point. But is "1, 5, 10, 25, and 50" really used in most of the world? I know the US uses it, but eg the EU uses 1, 2, 5, 10, 20, 50, 100, 200. Japan uses 1, 5, 10, 50, 100, 500. China uses 1, 2, 5, 10, 50, 100. Regarding notes, I always thought the USD was rather unique in having such small bills. Your point still makes sense, but the specific example seems a bit US centric.

Comment: @tim Ah, yeah, I forgot that the Euro cent coins use 20 instead of 25. AFAIK though, most of the ‘dollar’ and ‘peso’ systems use the same coin sizes as the US dollar system. The general point still applies to most other decimal system although, although JPY and RMB are both somewhat less optimal than either EUR or USD.

Comment: "most of the dollar systems"  I surfed wikipedia and a quick count came out 20 to 19 in favour of 25c over 20c with more than 2 having neither. with the fractional pesos, there were three each way and two abstaining. if the euro is included as a "dollar" system it's evenly split.

Comment: @Jasen Huh, I actually had not realized that, though looking now it looks like most of the odd ones out are ones I actually did not know about or did not know used 20 cent coins instead of 25 cent coins. I’ve updated the answer to be a bit more specific and generalize less about this.

Answer (score 4):

Too few denominations, which lead to huge gaps between them.

If I want to buy something that costs 2 paulum and I have 1 radix, I get back 10 coins. If I have a decim, I get back 21 coins.

That means that people spend a lot of time counting coins that they give and receive. Additionally, sellers may need to carry huge amounts of spare change.

Without adding the base denominations, you need additional coins to make things easier.

At the very least, one half-radix, half-decim and so on.

You could also take advantage of the duodecimal system and issue coins that are a third of the base value, in exchange (or addition) to the half values. So you would have 1/3 radix and 2/3 radix coins, and perhaps 1/2 radix coins too.

Also, keep in mind that even basic mathematical literacy was not common in old times, so probably people would have a easier time with these new coins having different names than just describing them as "1/3 radix" or "4 paulum".

Incidentally, IIRC at least some of the denominations of the old (pre-decimalization) UK currency system worked like that.

Comment: There's no real use of the 2/3 radix. It is only two coins if you you have a 1/3 radix. It would be better to have 1/4 radix and 1/3 radix coins. Any change from 1 to 12 radix can be made with a maximum of three coins with these denominations. The currency should have more granularity at the bottom end where most transactions take place.

Answer (score 2):

You monetary system mimics the former [British pre decimal system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C2%A3sd) of pounds, shillings and pennies, where one shilling was 12 pennies and one pound was 20 shillings, thus one pound was 240 pennies.

The British system had coins of intermediate value to make things, like change easier.

There was half a penny, a three penny coin (threepence), a sixpence and a florin was two shillings.

You need some intermediary coins or worth 3 & 6 paulums and 2 and maybe 6 radixes.

Answer (score 1):

### Needs more denominations

Four denominations are nowhere near enough to cover the entire span of one currency, especially if you're dealing with a powerful economy that would enable large transactions. As it stands with four denominations you could easily end up with a scenario that would require a buyer to haul an entire carriage with half a dozen oxen just to provide a payment for a single valuable commodity. Buying on bulk would be an obscenely nightmarish thing under the circumstances.

The number of denominations is directly proportional to the buying power of the currency in question. Most modern currencies have 10 denominations and the ones being chosen are the ones most often found in circulations.

1, 2, 5, 10, 20, 50, 100, 200, 500, 1000.

Naturally, common sense dictates that any transactions that would require an amount of denominations that couldn't be physically held within a single hand should be concluded with a sale contract.

Answer (score 1):

There are plenty of historical precedents, including in late classical antiquity, for a mixed system of coins that are actually made of precious metal, and others that are just tokens.

In developing how your system works in practice, you could consider "[Gresham's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gresham%27s_law)" that *bad money drives out good*. If people have a high degree of trust that both kinds of coin are acceptable, then they may tend to hoard the gold for themselves (or trade it with external parties, or melt it down), and do most business using the lesser denominations. That's because they can get the same practical day-to-day trade value either way, but only the gold is valuable for external trade or making into jewellery. Conversely, if there's a lack of trust that twelve decim are just as good as an aureus, then people may prefer to use gold coins (or snipped fractions of them) - assuming they are wealthy enough to use that amount of money. Effects may be different for different regions of your polity, or different parts of society.

Switching to the government's-eye-view, consider how they might enforce the desired equivalence of coins. Do they pay their workers and suppliers in gold, or deliberately choose lesser denominations? Perhaps some people who deal with the state get preferential treatment. Do they attempt to fix prices of various commodities (as various historical governments have tried)?

Comment: U can improve answer. Do not leave rethorical questions unanswered or without examples. If people do not know and looking for the answers they won't be able to answer them, there is nothing to recall for them and they already came from google

Answer (score 1):

I will make a few assumptions here, feel free to clarify.
In terms of stability, there are at least two things to look at:

**1. Intrinsic Value / Scarcity**

On tying an enumeration of money to a fixed amount of scarce and precious resource, good. You've just hedged a little at least against the primary financial crisis of the modern world. Intrinsic value (and by implication, scarcity) is one of [the Aristotelian properties of money](https://omniequivalence.com/monetary-properties/). A better standard would be to have the money **be** the precious substance; that way hoarding the gold to conceal the true amount of value and printing arbitrary amounts of worthless paper or trinkets would not be possible. In order to be sustainable as a standard, the rare substance itself must be in circulation.

**2. Counting and Numeric Efficiency, and Divisibility**

The numeric efficiency of the coinage is related to a second and third of Aristotle's four criteria, namely, portability and divisibility. As mentioned in another answer, you've chosen a counting system that is cumbersome, because large amounts of coinage will be needed to make change for almost any purchase.

The most efficient number system is an augmented binary counting system*, where the general rule is that each coin denomination is worth twice that of the next lower value. The basic value set could be something like 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, and 32. When the sum becomes an amount where the total number of coins becomes excessive, a second summary value of coin can be introduced, which is equal in value to the sum of a certain run of preceding coins. For example, you could have a 1, a 2, and a 3, since 1 and 2 combinations are common. For larger sums, you could have a 1, 2, 3, 4, 8, 16, and 32, plus a coin valued at 31 (for those $9.99 purchases). The maximum number of coins required for any amount 1-32 is therefore 4, one less than the logarithm base two of the number. The summary coins can be kept sparse, thereby preventing doubling the number of coins required, and keeping in general the number of coins required to make any amount of change logarithmic in terms of the amount, with an additional reduction for very common amounts. (Imagine having a dime+nickel coin 25 years ago; how often that would have come in handy). Time to count coins will be greatly reduced because any amount requires ***at most*** one of each value of coin. The efficiency gain of this greatly increased portability is most notable when portage costs are high, such as in a civilization where the item you purchase must be carried home on a human back or using only small draft animals, when distances are long and travelers are on foot, and every gram of coinage costs them something dear to lug around.

So your coinage system will not have those advantages. It is more likely that it belongs to a decadent civilization having advanced technology for transportation or else the money articles are very small and lightweight; that the people of this civilization are soon going to be subjected to a standard change for the value of their currency since (as I understand it) the currency itself is not a precious substance; they may already be seeing the effects of inflation as gold is being hoarded and relatively worthless trinkets are being mass-produced in lieu of precious materials in order to pay government debts, and the inefficiency of purchases and exchanges with that coinage is pushing them towards a digital or otherwise more convenient currency. The lack of higher denominations also means that the base-12 system devolves into unary for amounts greater than the largest; if the smallest denomination is close to a cent than the largest will not be much more than 17 dollars. Counting large sums, including a day's wages, quickly becomes burdensome and perhaps even prohibitive in this case, although the granularity is perhaps feasible for coarse-grained purchases, but does not perform well at the extremes of high or low value. Other realms will be pressuring this civilization in that direction on account of the exchanges; the burden of exchanging vast enumerations of minor flotsam greatly increases their accounting expenses without enriching themselves commensurately.

**[This coinage system was borrowed shamelessly from [here](https://www.churchofjesuschrist.org/study/scriptures/bofm/alma/11?lang=eng).]*